# Replacing a certain letter in a string and removing trailing vowels in R

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to remove all certain letter, for example 'M', preceded or followed by a vowel in R. So, I've written...

```
gsub ('(A|E|I|O|U)\\M','\\',"MICHAEL")
```

Here I tried to eliminate all 'M's in a string that is preceded by a vowel. Obviously, the replacement is wrong.. and I am not sure how to code this...

Also, is there a way to code this in a same line instead of writing two different lines of codes, one for preceded and the other for followed by a vowel?

Another question is...
I have found a way to remove trailing spaces in R, but any idea of how to removed trailing vowels at the end of a string in R?

Comment: This might be useful: http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html

Comment: I would provide a vector with strings and define more what you want. Add some expected output for all the strings.[Here are the r docs for regex](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html)

Comment: Thank you for the links to the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, how to make it all in one line, but here is some working code:

```
# remove M, if the wowel is immediately after or immediately before
gsub('([AEIOU])M|M([AEIOU])','\\1\\2','AAAMLICHAELMLMAAAAAA')    

# remove vowels in the beginning
gsub('^(A|E|I|O|U){1,}','',"AAAMICHAEL")
# remove vowels in the end
gsub('(A|E|I|O|U){1,}$','',"AMICHAELAAAA")
```